# AWS NAT over Direct Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, nat, aws-direct-connect

I have an issue in AWS where my remote direct connect sites unfortunately have over lapping address space and they both need access to an application running on a EC2 instance. I have the ability to NAT the remote sites and advertise the SNAT addresses over the private VIF, but I there a way to hide the EC2 instance behind NAT as well? So I have NAT both sides (in AWS hiding the EC2 instance hosting the APP and on my remote site) My application sources TCP to the remote sites and also receives TCP sessions sourced from the remote sites so I need bidirectional.

Comment: Why not install a virtual router in the VPC ? There are appliances like these in the AWS markeplace.

Comment: I agree but then resilience becomes an issue, IE propagating routes backing into the VPC from the EC2 instance (virtual router). I did think about implementing two routing devices within two AZs but the route selection becomes an issue.. unless you know something I don’t (highly likely!)

Comment: @Grev - did you try something with the Transit Gateway? You may be able to use it to do all the routing that you describe. It runs in multiple AZs, and scales automatically, so all that is covered, too

Answer (score 0):

As your design, you need to do NAT traversal or the two sides behind NAT can not connect to each other. So maybe you need to build to do something like NAT-PMP or Upnp to realise it.